# How to make an button which shows an image

Tags: html, image, button

I want to make an button on which user when click it will show an image, I want it for HTML:

Show image

Comment: [plese consult help section on how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you would like to show a image to the user only when the user clicks on a button.

This is possible with JavaScript:

```
<html>

<body>
<img src="/path/to_img" style="display:none" id="myImage"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myImage.style.display='block';">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Yes, exactly what I want! Do you know if I can set specific dimensions for the image which will appear after the user clicks on a button?

Comment: You can set the dimensions via css:
*width: 100px; height: 120px;*.